# Indexing rows by boolean expression and column by position pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I set the values of a pandas dataframe slice, where the rows are chosen by a boolean expression and the columns are chosen by position?

I have done it in the following way so far:

```
>>> vals = [5,7]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[5,5,7,7]})
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  5
1  2  5
2  3  7
3  4  7
>>> df.iloc[:,1][df.iloc[:,1] == vals[0]] = 0
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  0
1  2  0
2  3  7
3  4  7
```

This works as expected on this small sample, but gives me the following warning on my real life dataframe:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

What is the recommended way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, when you do chained-indexing (not recommended in pandas), you will get this setting with copy warning.   One way to quickly spot chained inddexing is looking for '][' in statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use index of column header and `loc` (label based indexing):

```
df.loc[df.iloc[:, 1] == vals[0], df.columns[1]] = 0
```

Another way is to use `np.where` with `iloc` (integer position indexing), np.where returns the tuple of row, column index positions where True:

```
df.iloc[np.where(df.iloc[:, 1] == vals[0])[0], 1] = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) and [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
col = df.columns[1]
df.loc[df.loc[:,col] == vals[0], col] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be also done with a combination of loc and iloc:

```
df.loc[df.iloc[:,1] == vals[0]].iloc[:, 1] = 0
```